# Sort Stacked Bars in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

### I'm trying to sort stacked bars with Google's API, but the data can be only sort by columns:

> data.sort([{column:0, desc: True}]);

### Any ideas?

Below an example code:

```js
            google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart"]});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ["Element", "a", "b", "c", "d"],
                ["x", 2, 3, 2, 5],
                ["y", 0, 0, 14, 5],
                ["z", 7, 3, 4, 10],
                ["w", 2, 3, 0, 10]]
                );
                var options = {
                    bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
                    legend: {position: "top"},
                    chartArea: {
                        left: 100, top: 50, right: 0, bottom: 100, width: "100%", height: "100%"
                    },
                    isStacked: true,
                    hAxis: {
                        minValue: 1
                    }
                };
        
                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        
                var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("stackedChart"));
                chart.draw(view, options);
            }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="stackedChart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

[GOOGLE CHARTS STACKED BARS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C0bT.png)

Comment: do you want the order of the colors to be different for each row?

Comment: I want to sort each bar by stacked size:
a : ----------
b : ---
c : ------

Sorting --> 1st position: b, 2nd: c, 3rd: a

b: ---
c: ------ 
a: ----------

Comment: @DavidCastro, facing same problem friend. wonder if you found your solution and could help?

Comment: @Yogesh yes! sorry for the delay, what i did...was to sort in the backend (python) the array by size and pass that array to the front-end :/ it was the quickly solution at the moment but i believe you can do the same with length in javascript

Comment: @DavidCastro I had to do the same. But in JS, before passing it to the google charts :) Thanks btw.